# I would like to have only one opened panel (kind of an accordion menu)

Tags: jquery, css, hide, show

I would like to have only one opened panel (kind of an accordion menu).

What I tried so far is (the comment sections inside the code):

```
//$('#tabs-1').show(100);
//$('#tabs-2').hide();
//$('#tabs-3').hide();
```

If tabs-1 is selected `if ($('#tabs-1').is(":visible"))` then hide `tabs-2` and `tabs-3` will be hidden and `tabs-1` will be shown, but if I trigger and after that it will not react if I for example click on `tabs-2`, because `tabs-1` is still opened `('#tabs-1').is(":visible")` (it is caught in this block)
 and it cannot be closed. I know that this cannot work what I changed to the existing code, but I can not think of a different solution ...

May be take a look how the code looks like:

```
    function CloseTabInfo() {
        $(".BWTabVerticalTitle").on("click", function () {
            //alert("ausgeführt.");
            var contentDiv = $(this).attr("data-forcolapse");
            $(contentDiv).toggle(900);
            if ($('#tabs-1').is(":visible")) {
                //[START] Close other tabs, only one has to be opend 
                //$('#tabs-1').show(100);
                //$('#tabs-2').hide();
                //$('#tabs-3').hide();
                //[END]
                if ($("input:checked").val() == 1) {
                    $('.BWShipmentType').text('@BWHtml.translate("Documents")');
                }
                else if ($("input:checked").val() == 2) {
                    $('.BWShipmentType').text('@BWHtml.translate("Goods")');
                }
                //$('.BWShipmentType').text($("input:checked").val());
                $('.BWTabVerticalPreferences').text($('#shippingDetails_preferences').val());
            } else if ($('#tabs-2').is(':visible')) {
                //[START] Close other tabs, only one has to be opend 


                //$('#tabs-1').hide();
                //$('#tabs-3').hide();
                //$('#tabs-2').show(100);
                //[END]
                $('.BWSenderInfo').text($('#senderAddress_SenderAddress option:selected').text());
            }
            else if ($('#tabs-3').is(':visible')) {
                //[START] Close other tabs, only one has to be opend 

                //$('#tabs-1').hide();
                //$('#tabs-2').hide();
                //$('#tabs-3').show(100);
                //[END]
                $('.BWReceiverInfo').text($('#receiverAddress_matchCode').val());
                if ($('#shippingDetails_payment option:selected').text() != "Choose One") {
                    $('.BWPaymentInfo').text($('#shippingDetails_payment option:selected').text());
                }
                $('.BWCostInfo').text($('#shippingDetails_CostList option:selected').text());

            }
            else {
                //$('.BWShipmentType').text('');
                //$('.BWTabVerticalPreferences').text('');
                //$('.senderAddressInfo').text('');
            }
        });
```

I'm kind of new to jQuery, this makes it hard for me to solve this easy problem.

Comment: you should make a fiddle with html as well so that its easier for us to help you. **[CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be easily done with **[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)**, an official extension for jQuery which adds many UI elements, such as a Accordion or Tabs.

- [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Here is how you can easily implement an accordion:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
</script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 2</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Content 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```